# How to show file path in a textbox by default on starting WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox and a button along side it. The button click opens a folder browser to a default root folder from which I can select the files. I want to display this entire file path in the textbox automatically when I launch the application. This is the code that I have now.

```
    private void SelecttxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelecttxtBox.Text = fldDlg.SelectedPath;
    }
```

However, this inputs the path into the textbox AFTER the button click whereas I want to populate it BEFORE clicking on the button.

I appreciate the help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to display the "default root" path in the Textbox on startup? If yes, then you can set the the Text Property simply in the constructor, then it should set it right when you start your application:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SelecttxtBox.Text = "Whatever your root path is";
}
```

If you are new to WPF, I would as well suggest that you have a look into the MVVM pattern, as this is the "proper" way of how to separate Business Logic from the View, so not everything ends up in your code-behind.

Comment: Can I do it without hard coding the path?

Comment: yeah sure, I assume you have your FolderBrowser object, on which you should something like an "InitialDirectory" path (sorry I don't know the properties by heart :-).
Just set it to that value:
`SelecttxtBox.Text = fldDlg.InitialDirectory`